# Link C# SqlCommand to the SelectCommand of SqlDataSource on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Since I want to include a session variable in MySql `select` statement, I want to be able to write a `sql` string `select` statement in `.cs` page and reference it in the `SelectCommand` property in the `SqlDataSource` on the `.aspx` page.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlDataSource accepts Session parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx. Use it instead.

Comment: @JonH, just check his questions one by one. Specially for you I'm renew my remark.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy - my mistake - the new user page as has been discussed in meta is confusing by all means.  It is busy and chock full of text it is hard to understand what all the 0's were.  The 0's were for votes, you have to actually click the questions tab to see they were answered.  I really like the old design better, everything at one glance.  Too much going on in the new page.

Comment: @JonH, incorrect.  All of his previous questions have answers.  If you click the 'View More' link in the profile summary it takes you to the full listing.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/974047/user974047?tab=questions&sort=votes)

Comment: @Inuyasha - please read my comment Inuyasha that was posted 3 hours before yours...please see that it says "My mistake...".  Please read before you post.